# Is there an efficient way to compare each column's value between two DataFrames or Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, series

I have 2 DataFrames and I'm trying to find the best way to iterate over each row from df_a and see if any of the values are different from the corresponding row in df_b. If even one single value is different, I'd like to consider the rows to be different.

### Example:

#### df_a

```py
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['E1', 'E2', 'E3'], 
                     'NAME': ['John', 'Jane', 'Steve'], 
                     'ROLE': ['Analyst', 'Manager', 'Intern'], 
                     'LOCATION': ['San Francisco', 'New York City', 'Houston']})

    ID  NAME    ROLE      LOCATION
0   E1  John    Analyst   San Francisco
1   E2  Jane    Manager   New York City
2   E3  Steve   Intern    Houston
```

#### df_b

```py
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['E1', 'E2', 'E3'], 
                     'NAME': ['John', 'Jane', 'Steve'], 
                     'ROLE': ['Analyst', 'Manager', 'Analyst'], 
                     'LOCATION': ['San Francisco', 'Chicago', 'Houston']})

    ID  NAME    ROLE      LOCATION
0   E1  John    Analyst   San Francisco
1   E2  Jane    Manager   Chicago
2   E3  Steve   Analyst   Houston
```

In the 2 DataFrames above, I'd like to capture the fact that E2 and E3 have changed, so I can carry them forward in my code as "updated" rows.

My current approach is sort of "brute force", and is *very* slow for larger datasets. I'm curious if there is a more efficient/elegant approach than just explicitly iterating over all rows and columns. I should note that my actual data contains a few columns with free text fields, so I'm not sure if that could possibly be a source of my code's sluggish behavior.

#### Current approach

```py
df_updates = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_a.columns)

for ix, a_row in df_a.iterrows():

    # get the matching from from df_b
    b_row = df_b[df_b['ID'] == a_row['ID']].iloc[0]

    for column in a_row.index: 

        # check the column exists in df_b
        if column in b_row.index: 

            # check if the values are the same
            if a_row[column] != b_row[column]:

                # if anything is different, capture the row
                df_updates = df_updates.append(a_row, ignore_index=True)
                break # break from the current iteration because we already confirmed that something has changed
        else:
            # If the column does not exist in df_b, then it must be a new field
            df_updates = df_updates.append(a_row, ignore_index=True)
            break
```

This code would render these results:

```
    ID  NAME    ROLE    LOCATION
0   E2  Jane    Manager New York City
1   E3  Steve   Intern  Houston
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.merge`

```
df_merge = df_a.merge(df_b, on=df_a.columns.tolist(), how='left',indicator=True)

df_merge[df_merge['_merge'] == 'left_only'].drop(columns=["_merge"])

   ID   NAME     ROLE       LOCATION
1  E2   Jane  Manager  New York City
2  E3  Steve   Intern        Houston
```

Comment: Thank you. This got me what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Use `.duplicated` and filter for `df_b` in a new dataframe called `df_c`

```
df_a['df_name'], df_b['df_name'] = 'df_a', 'df_b'
df_c = df_a.append(df_b)
df_c = df_c[(~df_c.duplicated(['ID', 'NAME', 'ROLE', 'LOCATION'], keep=False)) &
        (df_c['df_name'] == 'df_b')].drop('df_name', axis=1)
df_c
```

Output:

```
    ID  NAME    ROLE    LOCATION
1   E2  Jane    Manager Chicago
2   E3  Steve   Analyst Houston
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge the rows for `df_a` and `df_b` :

```
rows_a = df_a.iloc[:,1].str.cat(df_a.iloc[:,2:],sep=',')

rows_b = df_b.iloc[:,1].str.cat(df_b.iloc[:,2:],sep=',')

result = df_a.loc[rows_a != rows_b]

print(result)


    ID  NAME    ROLE    LOCATION
1   E2  Jane    Manager New York City
2   E3  Steve   Intern  Houston
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.set_index` and `ne`:

```
df_a = df_a.set_index("ID")
df_b = df_b.set_index("ID")
print(df_a[df_a.ne(df_b).any(1)].reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   ID       LOCATION   NAME     ROLE
0  E2  New York City   Jane  Manager
1  E3        Houston  Steve   Intern
```

Answer (score 0):

df_b[ [not x.all() for x in (df_a==df_b).values]  ]

```
   ID   NAME     ROLE LOCATION
1  E2   Jane  Manager  Chicago
2  E3  Steve  Analyst  Houston
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are only interested in the updated rows in df_b, the most straightforward way is to select those rows from df_b, which are different from the corresponding rows in df_a

Since you defined "different" as "at least one field is different" you can get the boolean mask by using `np.any` rowwise.

```
import numpy as np
df_b[np.any(df_a != df_b, axis=1)]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.